# Start Screen session when background programs running

Tags: gnu-screen

I have Matlab running in a Linux session for almost 2 days, and afraid to lose the computations if my network connection fails. Will moving Matlab to the background and starting 'screen' be the answer for that?

Comment: Actually [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process) is more similar to the one I asked, as it deals with already-started processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, starting a screen session after a process is started will not help. What you can try is just putting the process in the background. On my Linux (Mint 17) I tried it with another shell and put 'sleep 100000` in the background.

Then I logged off the session and started a new one. The `sleep 100000` process was still running and the parent became process 1 (the init process).

Steps were:

```
sleep 100000
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

```
bg 1

ps -ef |grep sleep
testuser   7482  7320  0 14:44 pts/11   00:00:00 sleep 10000000
```

logoff

logon

```
ps -ef |grep sleep
testuser   7482     1  0 14:44 ?        00:00:00 sleep 10000000
```

Other systems like Solaris has the `nohup` command which allows you to specify a pid to immune to hangups.

Comment: The process is indeed still running, but you can't reconnect to it (STDIN/STDOUT). I needed to reconnect to the Matlab session.

Comment: Use `reptyr [-s] pid` in that case, as @Anthon suggested, to reconnect the file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your Matlab output will not magically appear in the `screen` session for that you need to first start `screen` then start the matlab session within it.
The same holds true for `tmux`.

If you want to reconnect the stdin/out of this running process to another you can try [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr)